# What's the usage of where in this sentence

Tags: word-usage

> In this section, we will consider a few problems `where` developers new to React often reach for inheritance, and show how we can solve them with composition.

In above sentence, the author used where to connect two sentence. I know that `where` means location. What's the usage of `where` in this sentence. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where means more than just physical location - see [definition 1b](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/where) (MW)

> at, in, or to what situation, position, direction, circumstances, or respect

So the statement you quoted could be re-phrased as

> ... we will consider a few problems in which the situation is that developers new to React ...

As you can see, it's much cleaner to just use "where".

Comment: what does `in problems` mean?

Answer (score 1):

*Where* is used here as a relative 'adverb' [I'd call it a *pro-PP*, *PP* standing for "preposition phrase"] with the antecedent *a few problems*. You may paraphrase

> ...a few problems **in which** developers [...] often reach for inheritance ...